# Dell XPS 18: Touchscreen works on OpenSuse! How to do it in Ubuntu?

Tags: xorg, dell, tablet, touchscreen

On my Dell XPS 18 Tablet-PC, the touchscreen is known not to work in Ubuntu.

I just tried the OpenSuse Factory KDE Live CD. After installing a few extra packages - see

http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.tablet.html#sec.tablet.install

touching the screen worked like a charm without rebooting or relogging.

I tried to install the same (or similarly) named packages in an Ubuntu 13.04 Live System - doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to transfer it to Ubuntu? I really don't wanna use Suse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed 13.10 by following this [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2108450)

From this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2108450) I learnt that I needed to execute:

```
dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
```

for the Ubuntu installer to see the disk partitions.

Then I followed [this](http://www.techassistbox.com/solved-asus-q200e-usbest-technology-sis-hid-touch-controller_42382.html) guide to update the Linux kernel

Thanks to these guides I now have an XPS 18 with Windows 8 / Ubuntu and dual boot and Ubuntu touch screen working :-)

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link to the installation guide:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2108450